# How to identify if a system call is i/o related?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls

Recently i have a task to idenity the i/o related system calls.
I searched around about it on the internet and get somethings like: the basic i/o system calls are `write`, `read`, `open`, `close` and `lseek`.

But after futher search, i read about that there are memories i/o and network i/o.The network i/o are used to build a socket connction, and there are some system calls like:`socket`, `bind`, `listen` , etc.

All the source code of these system calls are located in **net/socket.c** ,
so i wonder if the memories i/o are the same, `read` ,`write` are from **fs/read_write.c** and `open` , `close` are from **fs/open.c** , and there are other system calls from same file.But the man page shows that the `truncate` , which is also from **fs/open.c** , is a command rather than a system call.

I'm doubt, if this is a right way to find i/o related system calls? Should i check through the system call tables to find i/o system calls?   i think there might have some easy way to identify it, but i didn`t find many discuss about it on the internet.

** I use [example/syscalls.rs](https://github.com/ranweiler/pete/blob/main/examples/syscalls.rs) from [pete](https://github.com/ranweiler/pete) , which is written in rust, to identify all system call a command used. It will get the system call number, match it with the system call table and out put the name of the system call. I extend the code with an array contains the numbers of the i/o system calls, if the number is in the array then output the name, otherwise not. But i need to add numbers manully.

Comment: I don't think there's any automatic way. You just have to know what all the system calls do.

Comment: What’s your definition of “i/o related”? Why is it important to you to know which syscalls fit that definition?

Comment: @Sneftel my task is to build an automatic testing framework (fuzz) for system call interceptors. and the roadmap lead me to do this. My tutor said that it should not be not only 5 basic i/o system calls

Comment: @Barmar get it, thanks after all, i`m starting at it